# NoComponentId error while creating ClientSidePage in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to create a ClientSidePage in SharePoint using CSOM in C# using the below code:

```
Web web = this._ClientContext.Web;
this._ClientContext.Load(web);
this._ClientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
var sitePagesList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");
this._ClientContext.Load(sitePagesList);
this._ClientContext.Load(sitePagesList.RootFolder);
this._ClientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
this._ClientContext.Load(sitePagesList.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
this._ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var pageLibraryUrl = sitePagesList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
string newpagename = "MyNewClientPage1.aspx";
var newPageUrl = pageLibraryUrl + "/" + newpagename;
var newpage = sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(newPageUrl, TemplateFileType.ClientSidePage);
this._ClientContext.Load(newpage);
this._ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The page is shown inside the Site Pages. But when I try to open it, following error I get on the browser:

> > Sorry, something went wrong
>
> NoComponentId
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: e405339f-00d6-0000-4612-b10fedf0df16
>
> Date and Time: 2/6/2020 9:58:06 PM

Can anyone help me out with that what ComponentId here refers to ?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the page, you need to set the below page attributes to load properly.

```
        newpage["ContentTypeId"] = "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118";  
        newpage["Title"] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("MyModernpage.aspx");  
        newpage["ClientSideApplicationId"] = "b6917cb1-93a0-4b97-a84d-7cf49975d4ec";  
        newpage["PageLayoutType"] = "Article";  
        newpage["PromotedState"] = "0";  
        newpage["CanvasContent1"] = "<div></div>";  
        newpage["BannerImageUrl"] = "/_layouts/15/images/sitepagethumbnail.png";  
        newpage.Update();  
        ctx.Load(newpage);  
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Further read: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-modern-site-page-using-csom